# How to pass data from recyclerview adapter to fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to pass data from recyclerview adapter to fragment.I have already check the links in stack overflow but unable to get right code.

Comment: show your code so we can analyze what is happening

Comment: you can use call back listeners by using interface

Comment: Use bundle to pass data, create a bundle and set it to the fragment using setArguments(Bundle)

Answer (score 2):

Most efficient and professional method

Using CallBacks to communicate between adapter and fragment:

In Adapter:

```
 private Callback mlistener;

   public Interface Callback extends EventListener{

     public void onPassData(int data);

           }

   public void setListener(Callback listener)
    {
    this.mlistener = listener;
    }
```

And then you can Call listener method from anywhere in adapter as:

```
    mlistener.onPassData(4);
```

Receive Call back in Fragment:

```
   adapter.setListener(new Callback) {
   @Override
   public void onPassData(int data)
    {

   //YOu will receive data here whenever you call onPassData

   }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public interface AdapterCallback{
    void onReponse(Object data);
 }
```

## In Adapter Contructor

```
CustomAdapter(...., AdapterCallback mCallback){
....
}
```

Call in Adapter like:

```
mCallback.onResponse(data);
```

## Creating instance of adapter:

```
CustomAdapter obj = new CustomAdapter(....,new AdapterCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onReponse(Object data) {

    }
});
```